# Power Automate Disabling Infrequently Used Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

**How can I prevent infrequently run flows from being automatically disabled?**

I recently received an email about a flow I have that doesn't run very often with the following message:

> We noticed that your flow has not run at all in the past 90 days. If it does not run it will be turned off in 7 days.

This is very inconvenient for me, but I can't find any documentation regarding this policy or how to disable it (if that's even possible).

Some possibly relevant details:

- We are using the Microsoft Power Automate Free license with Microsoft 365 E3
- This flow is part of a document approval process and doesn't make sense to have run periodically to avoid this apparent 90-day limit.

Has anyone else encountered this / has anyone had success disabling this feature?

**Update 2021-02-19**

My [posting](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-can-I-prevent-infrequently-run-flows-from-being/m-p/769341#M62196) the to Power Automate forum has a few responses at this point, mostly just other users noting that they have the same problem. One user posted a [link](https://sharepains.com/2020/12/02/re-enable-flows-power-automate/amp/) to a guide on creating a *additional* flow that re-enables the disabled flows. For my part, I decided not to pursue that painful workaround, and for now am just re-enabling them whenever I get an email that a flow was disabled.

Comment: Run duration and retention is 30 days as per [MS doc[(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config). Are you using **trial** license for MS Flow?

Comment: @MatiurRahman This is not regarding run duration or retention. The flow in question has not been triggered at all in the past 90 days as the email states. I don't think this is a trial license - the 'subscription' page of the Office account that hosts the flows shows the license as "Microsoft Power Automate Free."

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a limit written in official documentation, nor have I found any settings related to this feature. From my point of view, it would be an action preventing overload on service.
To further confirm this setting, you may post in the Power Automate forum where you can get dedicated support on Flow: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Power-Automate/ct-p/FL_GeneralDiscussions

Comment: I've posted this question in the PA forum and will update this question with anything I learn from there.

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate Free, Trial, Community and Microsoft 365 plan licences are now subject to expiry after 90 days, whereas a dedicated per-flow or per-user licence isn't subject to these limits.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#expiration-limits

It looks like this is by design to help encourage you onto a paid plan for critical flows.

There are some workarounds involving using a separate scheduled Flow to automatically re-enable suspended flows. [The approach the OP found](https://sharepains.com/2020/12/02/re-enable-flows-power-automate/) is to have a flow loop through your environments and re-enable any flows it finds with a suspended status, and this is quite an involved-looking Flow with a lot of steps. I also found that some details appeared to be missing/left to guesswork to recreate the flow myself.

[Another way](https://mofumofupower.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/11/13/104740) which appears simpler is to create a Flow that triggers from the incoming warning email, parses out the environment and flow from the email itself, and re-enables the flow that way. If you try this one, note that there's a typo in the last lines before the end of the article, as both the environment and flow appear to have the same code (and shouldn't). One of the lines:

```
split(outputs('Compose_-_extract_url'),'/flows/')?[0]
```

should be

```
split(outputs('Compose_-_extract_url'),'/flows/')?[1]
```

Unfortunately due to some other issues I'm having, I've not been able to work out which is which. However, this Flow is only 3 steps long, and might be easy to put in place.